# modx: eForm remembering field input on error

Tags: modx

After I submit the form unsuccessfully, the form looses all the values I typed in.

I'm using value="", so that could be related, but if I remove it I get a `/` in the field, and it still doesn't remember

any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out. I had all the intention of going in and adding the functionality, when I came across line 573 in eform.inc.php "# get SESSION data - thanks to sottwell"
so it's already doing what I want it to.

anyhow, because I couldn't find this in any documentation here is what I've done. Though I must say faintly recall doing this exact thing before. So the next time I need this I might come across this :)

add a value=[+*field*+]

```
<input id="femail" name="email" value="[+email+]" eform="Email Address:email:1" />
```

just remember that the value needs to match the class and NOT the id(unless you want them the same)

Answer (score 0):

well for now I've used a javascript to do this, it works well but maybe someone has a php/modx/eform solution.

Answer (score 0):

By unsuccessfully submitting the form do you mean it fails validation checks?

No matter what I do, I can't replicate the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: ya, so when the validation fails, I loose whatever I entered into the fields, if it's one or two fields it's ok, but but with a plethora of fields it can get really annoying having to fill everything out again